# gitlab-ci: Automatically increment version on merge commits

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I did not really know how to phrase that so my question *might* look confusing but let me explain:

Inside our codebase, we have implemented some basic versioning, which the CMakeLists.txt sets  dynamically. In theory, this works great! In practice, we *always* forget to increment the version accordingly.

So, something automatic is pretty much mandatory. Let's say I have a tool that generates a version from the current commit. I would like to automate this in a way that requires no human interaction, but I am not sure how to do this. I would like it to do the following:

- Whenever something gets merged to develop, generate a project version
- Set the CMakeLists project(VERSION) to that version
- Push a tag to origin

I was thinking of giving the gitlab-runner push access to the repository, and having it do it. However, that would create an additional commit **after** every merge commit right ? Which is problematic because well, the version is not synchronous with the commit that introduced the changes. There is the possibility of using `git amend`, but I am not very used to it. Theoretically, modifying the merge commit to patch the CMakeLists and force pushing it would do what I want, but I am not very aware of the problems that could cause for other contributors.

Maybe I'm completely missing something and there's an easier way of doing it. If so, please enlighten me !

Comment: `I would like it to do the following:` Do exactly that, but before `Push a tag to origin` you have to also do `git commit `and `git push` that commit.

Comment: But will that not create an additional commit on top of the one that is getting merged ? Ideally I would want the changes to be integrated in the actual merge commit. This requires an amend, right ?

Comment: `This requires an amend, right ?` Yes. But most importantly, it also _requires a rebase from all developers_, and that rebase would have to be manual (with `--onto` argument). I believe this would cause chaos in the long run, but sure. You can `--amend` and `git --force` it.

Comment: You could calculate a version number and tag your commit, this does not require pushing *new commits*. You generally do this in your CI/CD pipeline.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen The thing is we need to know the project version at runtime (it is defined inside the CMakeLists) because we perform several checks. So I would like to simply patch that file on merge requests.

Comment: The only way to not use an additional commit nor tag is to store version data in an external system - this is what we do with Reliza Hub. The idea is to put placeholder for the version that is resolved at the CI run. See sample placeholder here (note, it's GitHub Actions not Gitlab, but it doesn't matter in this case): https://github.com/relizaio/reliza-cli/blob/master/cmd/version.go and then sed instruction on line 51 in our CI script: https://github.com/relizaio/reliza-cli/blob/master/.github/workflows/dockerimage.yml

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to version or tag incrementally in Gitlab CI/CD when merging from Production to Master branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63633737/how-to-version-or-tag-incrementally-in-gitlab-ci-cd-when-merging-from-production)